# Convert Month Days Into Weekdays Per Week In SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, calendar, grid

I have a calendar table and I want to show each month in a grid, and when I select a month from the table, I have some row with monthday and weekday columns, but I must convert it to multiple rows per week to show the month in the grid.
my select command to get month info is something like this

```
SELECT Monthday, Weekday FROM Calendar Where Month = 5
```

that Results to this :

```
Monthday | Weekday
--------- --------
   1          4
   2          5
   3          6
   4          7
   5          1
   6          2
   7          3
   8          4
   .          .
   .          .
   .          .
```

and I Want to Convert it To Something like this

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 
-- --- --- --- --- --- --
            1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   .   .   .
```

just like a calendar grid.
I think the answer is by Pivot, but I don't know how, Do you know a solution how to convert my select command?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what output you need?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: so fast negatives, at least give me time to edit my question guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a calendar table with the structure mentioned below, which is populated with a query like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    TheDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    YearNumber SMALLINT,
    MonthNumber SMALLINT,
    DayNumber SMALLINT,
    WeekdayNumber SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (TheDate, YearNumber, MonthNumber, DayNumber, WeekdayNumber)
SELECT x.TheDate, 
    YEAR(x.TheDate) AS YearNumber, MONTH(x.TheDate) AS MonthNumber, DAY(x.TheDate) AS DayNumber, 
    (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,x.TheDate)+@@DATEFIRST-2)%7+1 AS WeekdayNumber
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 365 DATEADD(DAY,N-1,'20210101') AS TheDate
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY low) AS N FROM master..spt_values) t 
    ORDER BY N
) x
```

The formula for `WeekdayNumber` is written this way to ignore the `SET DATEFIRST` setting and always consider Monday as the first day of week. If you prefer another day to be the first in the week, adjust `-2` to another value.

To display something like a calendar for a particular month, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DayNumber, WeekdayNumber, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DayNumber-WeekdayNumber) AS WeekNumber
    FROM dbo.Calendar WHERE YearNumber=2021 AND MonthNumber=5
) t
PIVOT (MAX(DayNumber) FOR WeekdayNumber IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) p
```

This produces the following result:

```
WeekNumber           1      2      3      4      5      6      7
-------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
1                    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   1      2
2                    3      4      5      6      7      8      9
3                    10     11     12     13     14     15     16
4                    17     18     19     20     21     22     23
5                    24     25     26     27     28     29     30
6                    31     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

I am using just the `DayNumber` and `WeekdayNumber` columns to compute a week number  and then I am using `PIVOT` to arrange the values for DayNumber in the desired format.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for, thank you!